# Different labels per page layout

Tags: page-layout, customlabel

Is there a chance we can have different field label per page layout? For example... I have 2 account record types and i want a field in one record type to be BirthDate and in another date founded.

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to add the second field? Is there a benefit to storing data that's semantically different in the same field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one level, it's possible, and that's when dealing with translated labels based on user locale.

What you're proposing different. As a design choice, this pattern is understandable under some circumstances in other platforms where perhaps optimizing for storage is a goal.

However in the multi tenant custom object/field model, this kind of optimization doesn't really buy you any benefit. The "cost" of data storage for a record is identical, whether that record has 2 fields, or 200 fields.

In fact, the standard UI features of the platform are really designed around adding an extra field in precisely this type of circumstance.

You then use each field for each respective page layout.

In general, for Salesforce data model, I'd suggest you store data that is semantically different in different fields. Even if it is kind of similar, as is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to show a field in both layouts with different-2 labels.
This feature is not available at the moment.
But if you want to see this field is read-only in different page layout, you can create a formula field for another page layout with a different label.

I hope it will work.